# No IUserTokenProvider named 'Default' is registered

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identity, change-password

I'm making use of an ASPNET Core API where we do our authentication. Everything works fine, except for the fact that it complains about not having an IUserTokenprovider whenever I try to get change a password with *GeneratePasswordResetToken*.
We get an error like "No IUserTokenProvider named 'Default' is registered."

We make use of different databases for different customers, so we want to provide a connectionstring to the context so that each call will be able to refer to a different database. As far as I understand, that's not possible when you do that in the startup. We then tried to do that in the DbContext and the UserManager, which works.

Our code now looks like this (only relevant parts):

**Startup**

```
 public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(options => 
        {
            options.Tokens.ProviderMap.Add("Default", new TokenProviderDescriptor(typeof(IUserTwoFactorTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>)));
        })
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
     }
```

**DbContext**

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
private static string _connectionString

    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options, string connectionString) : base (options)
    {
        _connectionString = connectionString;

    }
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(_connectionString);
        base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
    }
}
```

**UserManager**

```
public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser>
{
public ApplicationUserManager(string connectionString, ApplicationDbContext context) : base(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context), null, new PasswordHasher<ApplicationUser>(), null, null, null, new IdentityErrorDescriber(), null, new Logger<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>(new LoggerFactory()))
    {                
        this.Options.Tokens.PasswordResetTokenProvider = TokenOptions.DefaultProvider;
        this.Options.Tokens.ProviderMap.Add("Default", new TokenProviderDescriptor(typeof(IUserTwoFactorTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>)));
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public async Task<string> ChangePasswordAsync(string userName, string oldPassword, string newPassword)
    {
         var connectionString = _tenant.OurDatabase.GetConnectionString();
          ApplicationDbContext applicationContext = new ApplicationDbContext(new DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext>(), connectionString);
          var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(connectionString, applicationContext);
          user = await manager.FindByNameAsync(userName);
          var token = await manager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user);
          var result = await manager.ResetPasswordAsync(user, token, newPassword);
    }
```

I already understood that the *IUserToken* should be replaced with the *IUserTwoFactorTokenProvider* for Core, as it doesn't exist in Core.

Since it doesn't work, I also tried adding it to the Startup, but apparently that doesn't really drizzle through to the Usermanager.

There's a lot of useful content to find, but so far none of them worked for me, probably because we don't do the default DI in the Startup.

When I step through the code, I do see that the Options.Tokens have a PasswordResetTokenProvider and also a Default provider route. But when I reach the GeneratePasswordTokenAsync, I still get that error message.

Does anyone know why I still get that message? Or what I'm doing wrong?